# Switch README from Markdown to Org, having problem with image rendering

Tags: org-mode, git, inline-image

I have a [repository](https://gitlab.com/samplehive/sample-hive) on `Gitlab`, I'm trying to change my `README` from  `Markdown` to `Org`,  I'm fully able to make the changes, but for reasons the the images are  having some sizing issues, they expand outside of the document itself.  I'm trying to figure out how to fix this?

Here is a screenshot to help  explain the situation better,
[image]

As you can see the image is exceeding the width of document, and page is scroll-able horizontally.

This screenshot is from a private test repository, I was testing how `Org` renders before I update my original repository.

Here is the code where I add this image,

```
#+CAPTION: Screenshot of SampleHive
#+ATTR_HTML: :alt logo-hive :title SampleHive Logo :align left :width 500
[[file:assets/screenshots/screenshot-hive.png]]
```

Comment: I don't know how GItlab renders the README: are you exporting it to HTML? If not, then the `#+ATTR_HTML` stuff is irrelevant. You might want to add some explanation to your question about how Gitlab renders such a README. Is there any guidance from them?

Comment: Actually, it might be relevant: what is the value of the variable  `org-image-actual-width`?

Comment: I don't know how Gitlab renders their `Org` `README`, I tried asking on their `Reddit` but got no response yet. Value for the variable `org-image-actual-width`, if I do `describe-variable` on it, is `nil` and it says original value is `t`.

Comment: OK - the description of the variable says that if it is nil, then it will look for any `#+ATTR` declaration of the width and use that, otherwise fall back to the original width - so it *should* work. Does it make any difference if you change the `:width 500` to, say, `:width 200`?

Comment: If I change `:width` to anything it does change inside Emacs, if I toggle `org-toggle-inline-images`, but on Gitlab it does nothing. Looking around on internet for other people's `Org` `README` on Gitlab, I found one that had `acsiinema` session video on his/her `README`, and looking at the raw file, I found he/she was doing this, `#+HTML: <a href="LINK HERE" target="_blank"><img src="IMAGE PATH HERE" width="800"/></a>. I tried this, and this seems to work. Wonder why the other one doesn't. Here is the [link](https://gitlab.com/psachin/setV/blob/master/ReadMe.org) if you want to see yourself.